# Aligning a .data or .text section

Tags: linker, alignment, cortex-a

I am building a bootloader for an ARM Cortex-A9 target. The output of the Microsoft linker is passed to a locator application (romimage) that locates the linker output section and builds the linear memory layout that runs in the target.

One part of the bootloader is the MMU table that must be located at a 64k aligned boundary. The table is defined in its own section:

```
    AREA |.mmu|, DATA

    global MmuTable
MmuTable
    %   0x10000

    end
```

There are not other modules that create an output to section `.mmu`. The linker command line includes these options:

```
-DRIVER -SECTION:.mmu,R,ALIGN=65536
```

But the symbol MmuTable is not aligned at a 64k boundary.

How can the Microsoft linker (version 11.00.50728.6) be instructed to place a section aligned to a 64k boundary?

Comment: Looks like you can specify "/ALIGN" using the linker https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx